# Asp.Net Identity external login issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, identity

I have a problem using Asp.Net Identity.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application where there is an ApplicationUser class which is inherited from IdentityUser class. I am not using separate AuthenticationContext, I have just one DbContext.

I am working on the website authentication and I want to use Facebook login in my App.

I applied the necessary settings and when I click on the facebook button I get this exception in the AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback method.

> ```
> > Invalid column name 'User_Id'.    Description: An unhandled exception
> > occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
> > review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
> > it originated in the code. 
> > 
> >  Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column
> > name 'User_Id'.
> > 
> > Source Error: 
> > 
> > 
> > 
> > Line 220: Line 221:            // Sign in the user with this external
> > login provider if the user already has a login Line 222:           
> > var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login); Line 223:    
> > if (user != null) Line 224:            {
> ```

It's really strange for me because there is not user_id column in database.
I use Code First Migration and I know when a class has a complex property but does not have the foreign key property the Code First Migration will generate foreign key property in the db.

So, I am lost, I tried to debug it but I dont have any result.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: does it work when authenticating with Google? same error?

Comment: It doesn't. I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with external login. Somewhere, something is looking for a `User_Id` column, which of course doesn't exist because that's the error you're getting.

That format of column name is generally from a code-first conventions-based foreign key, i.e. there's a class that has `public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }` and no explicit id property for storing that relatonship. As a result, Entity Framework will create and try to use a column in the table of the format `[NavigationPropertyName]_[EntityIdProperty]`: in this case, `User_Id`.

Normally, you wouldn't get far enough to get this type of error as Entity Framework would raise an exception first telling you that you needed to run a migration on your database. However, it's possible that you either changed from/to an explicit foreign key property or are using something like database-first, with migrations disabled.

Basically, you just need to find what entity has a navigation property to `ApplicationUser` without a corresponding property to hold the key, and then either add a `User_Id` column to the table that corresponds to that entity, or correct the code so that it looks for the right column name.